# How to run a command at regular intervals from the terminal ( every 5 seconds )

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I want to run a command at regular intervals  ( every 5 seconds ) from the terminal.

```
./script.sh
```

The above command gives me the O/P. I would like to see the real-time output of the script in my terminal.

PS: I don't want to run it as a cronjob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`watch` is used to run any command at regular intervals and displays the output of the command on the terminal window. It is useful when you have to execute a command repeatedly and watch the command output change over time.

```
watch -n INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS COMMAND
```

Command would be

```
watch -n 5 ./script.sh
```